launchd socket configuration for Gunicorn
I have the following working launchd configuration for Gunicorn (with Nginx as a proxy server):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.snafu.gunicorn-mysite</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/snafu/virtualdjango/bin/gunicorn</string>
        <string>-w</string>
        <string>5</string>
        <string>--bind=unix:/tmp/gunicorn-mysite.socket</string>
        <string>mysite.wsgi</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>snafu</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/snafu/Sites/mysite</string>
</dict>
</plist>

When I replace the Gunicorn parameter --bind with a launchd Sockets dictionary –
<key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockProtocol</key>
            <string>TCP</string>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/tmp/gunicorn-mysite.socket</string>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>Unix</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>

– the socket is created, but Nginx requests to the socket fail (timeout). A similar configuration with a systemd socket unit works quite well. How would I need to change the launchd plist in order to get the Sockets config working?
Thanks, Jan
